# DirectShow, video zoom and image capture for Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, directshow

I am currently developing an application for live video streaming (www.livecliq.net) and I would like to add the feature for image capture and video zoom.
I've been looking around for the tutorials and resources about DirectShow but so far I have found only a book "Programming Microsoft DirectShow for Digital Video and Television" which isn't of much help for advanced video manipulation.

Does anyone know whether is it possible and if, how to apply digital zoom on a captured video and how to capture photos with the device camera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've searched some time ago about capturing photos using DirectShow and the best I've found is this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx). The author has built a dll that exposes a function for capturing photos. It also mentions CameraCapture sample in the SDK that does video capture.